# How to Access Twitter API using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: ajax, api, twitter

> The Below Code Successfully retrives JSON data but it doesnot work on
>   localhost and jsFiddle

```
 var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\\\"Pd4vyx4AsNv3jdMja0cNCXilN\\\",oauth_signature_method=\\\"HMAC-SHA1\\\",oauth_timestamp=\\\"1537443447\\\",oauth_nonce=\\\"WsA8VV16BfF\\\",oauth_version=\\\"1.0\\\",oauth_signature=\\\"M%2BPZVPbFSnxkxeDxFLxC1eKYHdY%3D\\\""
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```